# Jquery wont populate values with ajax Json

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest

I was hoping one of you could point me in the right direction with this. I'm trying to create a Jquery script that populates a users city and state by entering their zip code.

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">//
// Make AJAX request
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$("#contact_phonenumber").keyup(function() {
var el = $(this);
if (el.val().length === 5) {
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/SECRETAPIKEY/info.json/"+  el.val() +"/radians",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            //data: "zip=" + el.val(),
            success: function(result, success) {
                $('input[name="tcity"]').append(result.city);
                $('input[name="tstate"]').append(result.state);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I'm using Tamperdata and I can see on Keyup that the zip is submitting the right request, here is the response

```
{"zip_code":"10001","lat":0.711233,"lng":-1.29149,"city":"New York","state":"NY","timezone":{"timezone_identifier":"America\/New_York","timezone_abbr":"EDT","utc_offset_sec":-14400,"is_dst":"T"},"acceptable_city_names":[{"city":"Empire State","state":"NY"},{"city":"G P O","state":"NY"},{"city":"Greeley Square","state":"NY"},{"city":"Macys Finance","state":"NY"},{"city":"Manhattan","state":"NY"}]
```

The code is not updating my form fields tstate and tscity though. I also tried selecting it by class and it won't update. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I trhink maybe to use val() instead of append() could do the trick

Comment: If you've confirmed the response is being correctly returned, you can deduce it must be your `.append` method. You can run that code in Chrome or Firefox console to verify it works like `$('input[name="tcity"]').val('test');`

Comment: Ok in the console I get the error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/secret/info.json/11220/radians?zip=11220&_=1471387444614. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). (unknown)

Answer (score 0):

use .val() instead

```
$('input[name="tcity"]').val(result.city);
$('input[name="tstate"]').val(result.state);
```

UPDATE: I created an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/m0rjjj/pen/rLRmoq). The problem is that you need to register a client-side access. Your API key will have a "js-" prefix.

Comment: I tried val & append already. I even tried loading a stating val right below the document ready to popular the form field. I think somehow the result.city is not "binding" to the json.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what append's effect on input elements,

But if you want to change the value of the input you should change the attritube "value" using val() or attr(), currently var() is the best option for your case.
I hope its work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//
        // Make AJAX request
        $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $("#contact_phonenumber").keyup(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.val().length === 5) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/SECRETAPIKEY/info.json/"+  el.val() +"/radians",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    //data: "zip=" + el.val(),
                    success: function(result, success) {
                        $('input[name="tcity"]').val(result.city);
                        $('input[name="tstate"]').val(result.state);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        });
        </script>
```